# SAS DDE not formatting output correctly in Excel

Tags: sas, export-to-excel, dde

I'm just looking to export a SAS dataset into a pre-made Excel template.

First 6 variables of my dataset (which is a .wpd file)  look like:

```
StartDate     EndDate    product_code   Description               Leaflet    Media
04-Jul-13    07-Jul-13    256554    BUTCHER BEEF 1PK (1 KGM)       54x10        3
```

I currently have:

```
options noxwait noxsync;
x '"c:\Template.xls"'; /* <--excel template to use*/
filename template dde 'excel|Leaflets!r6c1:r183c67';   /*put data in rows 3 to 183 in leaflets sheet*/


data LEAF.results; set LEAF.results;
file template ;
     put StartDate   EndDate   product_code   Description   Leaflet  Media  
         /*and the remaining 61 variables*/    
run;
```

The DDE procedure works and opens the excel sheet, but the data is not formatted correctly in excel and looks like this:

```
StartDate      EndDate      Product code   Description  Leaflet      Media
04 July 2013   07 July 2013    256554      BUTCHER         BEEF       1PK
```

As you can see it seems to have treated spaces as delimiters but I'm not sure of the syntax to change this 
- might also be worth noting that I have 67 variables in my actual dataset so didn't want to have to informat and format them all individually.

Also, is there a way to output this dataset into my excel template and then save the template as a different filename elsewhere on my c drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After trying every DDE option under the sun I finally stumbled across LRECL.

So,

```
options noxwait noxsync;
x '"c:\Template.xls"'; /* <--excel template to use*/
filename template dde 'excel|Leaflets!r6c1:r183c67' notab **LRECL=3000**;   /*put data in rows 6 to 183 in leaflets sheet*/


data LEAF.results; set LEAF.results;
file template ;
     put StartDate   EndDate   product_code   Description   Leaflet  Media  
         /*and the remaining 61 variables*/    
run;
```

I'm guessing the default length of characters allowed in each cell was too short, so increasing the length allowed means each cell doesn't get split into multiple cells?

source:
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/003-2011.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `file template ;` to use a delimiter of tab, ie, `file template dlm='09'x;`;

Also, in the filename, add 'notab':
filename template dde 'excel|Leaflets!r6c1:r183c67' notab;

Comment: thanks for this, i tried this earlier and the output is similar to specifying no delimiter. I've tried a variety of delimiters and none seem to work :/

Comment: Added one more suggestion.

Comment: Hello again. Just trying your suggestion above and it didn't seem to make a difference. It looks like as soon as it comes across a missing value, it starts a new line. No idea why this is happening, is there a way I can tell it to treat nulls as blanks and not as the end of a line? Thanks!